# I want to enable auto slider and infinite loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

var acch = 1;
$('.controls ul a').click(function() {
    var chno = $('.slider-container li').length;
    switch($(this).attr('data-gallery')){
        case 'slide-left': 
            if (acch < chno){
                acch++;
                startSlide(acch);
            }       
        break;
        case 'slide-right':
            if (acch <= 1){
                acch = 1;   
            }else{
                acch--;
                startSlide(acch);
            }
        break;  
    }
})

function startSlide(itemNo){
    var sTo = '#slider-item-' + itemNo;
    $('#home-top-content').scrollTo($(sTo), 300);   
}

$('.backToTop').click(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
})

})
</script>
```

This is the script listed above i need to enable auto slide function and infinite loop
http://aphex.fresh-pixel.com/
This is the link to theme which i am using, you can see the problem in slider

Comment: I think I know your question though I don't think you've actually asked it.

Comment: ?? ofcourse i dont know, i am not a programer, i need to workout for my theme

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow is not the site for 'plz send teh codez'-like questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this implemetation is better, since you can add any number of sildes in the design without any chage in the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.controls ul a').click(function() {
        moveSliders($(this));
    })

    function startSlide(element){
        $('#home-top-content').scrollTo(element, 300);   
    }

    $('.backToTop').click(function() {
         $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
    })

    setInterval(function(){
        moveSliders($('.controls ul').find('a.arrow-right'));
        },6000);

    function moveSliders(clickElement)
    {
        //Get li with class active if that count is zero put it as the first li
        var currentActive = $('.slider-container li.slide-active');
        var firstElement = $('.slider-container li:first');
        var lastElement = $('.slider-container li:last');
        if(currentActive.length == 0){
            firstElement.addClass('slide-active');
            currentActive = firstElement;
        }

        switch(clickElement.attr('data-gallery')){
            case 'slide-left': 
                //Next
                var nextElement = currentActive.next();
                if(nextElement.length == 0)nextElement = firstElement;
                $('.slider-container li.slide-active').removeClass('slide-active');
                nextElement.addClass('slide-active');
                startSlide(nextElement);
            break;
            case 'slide-right':
                //previous
                var previousElement = $('.slider-container li.slide-active').prev();
                if(previousElement.length == 0)previousElement = lastElement;
                $('.slider-container li.slide-active').removeClass('slide-active');
                previousElement.addClass('slide-active');
                startSlide(previousElement);
            break;  
        }
    }

})
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Nandakumar, that solved the infinite loop problem, but i also need to add a auto slider, I tried some ways but its just not working with this Script

Comment: using a `setInterval()` will convert the above code to a autoslider. I have updated the code (not tested, using the auto slider and the arrow click can cause some timing issues)

Comment: Thanks man that really solved the problem, Ill update you once the project is done.  Really appreciated :)